# Pushing a view controller onto a navigation controller from a tab bar button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with a button like so:

```
- (void) addButtonPressed:(UIButton *) sender
{    
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor regularColor]];

    PostViewController *post = [[PostViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:post animated:YES];
}
```

This code runs but the PostViewController is never shown and the tab bar controller remains.

How do I get to push to a new controller?

The NavigationController was created and StartViewController was add as rootController.

Then in StartViewController I have:

```
TabBarController *tab = [[TabBarController alloc] init];

    // Presentation
[self presentViewController:tab animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Can please show me your tab bar controller code how you have created?

Comment: Is your tab bar controller embedded in navigation controller ?

Comment: But as seen in question TabBarController is not embedded in navigation controller.

Comment: if your viewController is pushed then only it's child view controller get navigation controller of the root View controller , But in your case you are presenting , check navigationController is nil.

Comment: How do I embed it properly?

Comment: Oh so push instead of present then...

Comment: Yes. But go through human interface guideline , they explained when to push or present. If its required to present then you have to initialise new navigation controller with TabBarController instance and then present it.

Comment: Go through https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1 .

Answer (score 0):

in tab bar you need to create separate Navigation Controllers.

Suppose there are 3 tabs A, B and C. All the three tabs have functionality of navigation from one view to another. than you need to create three separate Navigation controllers eact pointing to Tab A, B and C. In this way you can navigate to any class within the specific Tab.

Check out this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html) for more details.

Hope this will help you. Happy coding :)

Comment: I was told you only create one navigation controller and set it with initRootViewController

Comment: Yes we do this when we have simple navigation based application

Comment: This only works if tab bar is your rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

You may need to embed your tab bar controller within a navigation controller, In your storyboard click on your `tabbarController` so that it is highlighted with all the blue lines and then go to Editor in Xcode choose embed IN> `UINavigationController` ..If you want to do it programatically then in your `AppDelegate` where you setup your Window just Use This::

```
UINavigationController*  navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];
navigationController.toolbarHidden=YES;
navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
self.window.rootViewController =navigationController;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .xib then you have to use `NSBundle` to load nib

if you are using storyboard then you need to use `prepareForSegue` to pass on data or just display it out